# VPN and Windows 10 conundrum

Tags: vpn

My client is using native Windows 10 (builtin) technology to create a VPN tunnel from a laptop in his house to his three colleagues in the field. They need to remotely access the resources on the laptop in his house. In order to do this W10 vpn is used. The problem is they cannot all access the laptop resources at the same time, as W10 builtin VPN technology does not accommodate this. It only allows one connection at a time.

The other problem is that W10 vpn doesn't offer split tunnelling, so a lot of the broadband bandwidth in the house is used by a vpn connection.

It may be best to install and configure something like a Cisco RV340W VPN Firewall behind an adsl modem in bridged mode to accommodate the vpn traffic. Is this possible without having a Windows server behind the Cisco firewall. Looking at the vpn configurations of the Cisco firewall, it looks as if it is only geared around servers, and not a Windows 10 laptop.

Many thanks.

Comment: It is possible, I would suggest to get a meraki in example. you simply allow to access the windows computer when the von is open, but they access files or a apps? as like rdp is limited to 1 session for client OS

Comment: When you say “access resources”, are you talking about access to files? If so, have you considered an alternative take on this problem and simply use a file synchronisation  service such as Dropbox? The field workers would have access to the files, but would not need to directly access the laptop in his house.

Comment: The network resource required for VPN access is a 'license' on the laptop which enables his colleagues in the field to run a specific type of petroleum modelling software application. The Windows 10 laptop which needs to be connected to is essentially a 'license' server. The license is a service running in the background and the remote laptops connected using vpn are then part of the local area network. Someone suggested a Synology Diskstation which can be used as a vpn server.